# On the evaluation of $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sin \left (\frac{1}{4x^2} \right ) \, dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

When attempting to find an alternative solution to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580285/is-it-possible-to-compute-int-infty-infty-x-sin-x-over-x41dx-withou), which called for the evaluation of the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x \sin x}{1 + x^4} \, dx$$
using real methods, I ran up against the following improper integral
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sin \left (\frac{1}{4 x^2} \right ) \, dx. \tag1$$
A value for this improper integral can be found. It is
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \exp \left (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right ) \sin \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right ),$$
and is what I am having trouble in finding.

I have tried a number of the various tricks one typically employs when attempting to find such integrals such as Feynman trick of differentiating under the integral sign, series solution, and so on, all to no avail (perhaps I missed something here).

One method that looked promising was to use [properties for the (inverse) Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis), namely
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty (\mathcal{L} f)(s) \cdot (\mathcal{L}^{-1} g)(s) \, ds.$$

After enforcing a change of variable $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sin \left (\frac{1}{4 x^2} \right ) \, dx &= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-1/(4x)}}{x^{3/2}} \cdot \sin x \, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathcal{L} \{\sin x\} \cdot \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left \{\frac{e^{-1/(4x)}}{x^{3/2}} \right \} \, ds\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{2 \sin (\sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{\pi}} \, ds\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{s \sin s}{1 + s^4} \, ds, \tag2
\end{align*}
where in the last line a substitution of $s \mapsto s^2$ has been made.

While this is a perfectly valid approach the only problem is the integral one ends up with in (2) is exactly the integral one started out with.

So my question is

> Is it possible to evaluate the integral given in (1) using real methods that does not depend on evaluating the integral given in (2)?

Comment: Have you tried using complex residues?

Comment: My preference is for a method that is real.

Comment: Hmm, I somehow missed the "real methods" part twice. Carry on then.

Comment: A method that evaluates the integral given in (2) using complex residues can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335664/integral-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-xx4a4-mathrmdx-using-residue If you feel residues make light work of (1) compared to finding (2) using a complex approach then by all means please share your solution.

Comment: But I would also like to see a real approach if possible.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was thinking. I don't really have any insight on (1). Best of luck though.

Comment: @omegadot I tried integration by parts on $u=\exp(-x^2)$ and $dv=\sin\frac 1{4x^2}\, dx$, but $v$ depends on the Fresnel C integral.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-\frac i{4x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{i^{1/4}}{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{i^{1/2}}2\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac{i^{1/4}}{\sqrt2}e^{-i^{1/2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{i^{1/2}}2\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac{i^{1/4}}{\sqrt2}e^{-i^{1/2}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{i^{1/2}}2\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2}\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\frac{i^{1/4}}{2\sqrt2}e^{-i^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{i^{1/2}}2u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag4\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{-i^{1/2}}\tag5\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{-\frac1{\sqrt2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac{i^{1/4}}{\sqrt2}x\quad$(this requires [Cauchy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem))
$(2)$: multiply by $e^{-i^{1/2}}e^{i^{1/2}}$
$(3)$: substitute $x\mapsto\frac1x$
$(4)$: average $(2)$ and $(3)$
$(5)$: evaluate integral$\quad$(this requires Cauchy's Theorem)
$(6)$: expand complex exponential

Both of the applications of Cauchy's Theorem above use the contour
$$
[0,R]\cup\left[Re^{i\left[0,\frac\pi8\right]}\right]\cup\left[Re^{i\frac\pi8},0\right]
$$
Looking at the imaginary parts of $(6)$, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin\left(\frac1{4x^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2e^{-\frac1{\sqrt2}}\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\tag7
$$

Answer (score 5):

Following tired's suggestion, the problem is equivalent to finding

$$\text{Im}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-x^2+\frac{i}{4x^2}\right)\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\left(x-\frac{1-i}{2\sqrt{2}\,x}\right)^2-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dx$$
and through a rotation of the integration line this can be easily computed through the Cauchy-Schlömilch substitution, the best known instance of [Glasser's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem):
$$\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^+,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-x^2-\frac{a}{x^2}\right)\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\,e^{-2\sqrt{a}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$ I=\int e^{-x^2} \cos \left (\frac{1}{4 x^2} \right ) \, dx\qquad  \qquad J=\int e^{-x^2} \sin \left (\frac{1}{4 x^2} \right ) \, dx$$

$$K=I+iJ=\int e^{-x^2+\frac{i}{4 x^2}}\,dx\qquad  \qquad \qquad  \qquad L=I-iJ=e^{-x^2-\frac{i}{4 x^2}}\,dx$$

$$-x^2+\frac{i}{4 x^2}=-\left(x^2-\frac{i}{4 x^2} \right)=-\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{-i}}{2 x} \right)^2+\sqrt{-i}$$
$$-x^2-\frac{i}{4 x^2}=-\left(x^2+\frac{i}{4 x^2} \right)=-\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{i}}{2 x} \right)^2-\sqrt{i}$$

All of that makes
$$K=\frac{ \sqrt{\pi }}{4} \left(e^{-(-1)^{3/4}}
   \left(-\text{erf}\left(\frac{(-1)^{3/4}}{2 x}-x\right)-1\right)+e^{(-1)^{3/4}}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(x+\frac{(-1)^{3/4}}{2 x}\right)+1\right)\right)$$
$$L=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}  \left(e^{-\sqrt[4]{-1}}
   \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1}}{2 x}-x\right)\right)+e^{\sqrt[4]{-1}}
   \left(\text{erf}\left(x+\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1}}{2 x}\right)-1\right)\right)$$ and then $I$ and $J$ and finally your result since 
$J=\frac{1}{2} i (L-K)$

**Edit**

Using Wolfram Alpha
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2+\frac{a}{x^2}}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  e^{-2 \sqrt{-a}}$$

Comment: You used Wolfram Alpha I'm guessing because of the signature $(-1)^{3/4}$...

Comment: @Crescendo. I finalized the calculation with another CAS which has the same signature.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just compute $K$ and then take its real part?

Comment: @Dylan. You are totally correct but don't you think that it is the same ? In nay way, I am an old fashioned man and this is what I use to do for more than 60 years ! Cheers :-)

Comment: No, I think it makes life easier to do one integral instead of two (half the work). Nonetheless, still a good answer +1

Comment: @Dylan. This is the problem with democracy : we may disagree !